# Bulma not working on Laravel 5.6

Tags: css, laravel, npm, sass, bulma

I was trying to install Bulma package through npm. it installed successfully with some warning but when I run 'npm run dev' , it shows error like below -

```
> ERROR in ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss Module build failed:
> ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: undefined
>                   ^
>       Index out of bounds for `nth($list, $n)`
>       in C:\Users\Sabbir\test\node_modules\bulma\sass\elements\button.sass
> (line 105, column 20)
>     at runLoaders (C:\Users\Sabbir\test\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:195:19)
>     at C:\Users\Sabbir\test\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:364:11
>     at C:\Users\Sabbir\test\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:230:18
>     at context.callback (C:\Users\Sabbir\test\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
>     at Object.asyncSassJobQueue.push [as callback] (C:\Users\Sabbir\test\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:55:13)
>     at Object.done [as callback] (C:\Users\Sabbir\test\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:7921:18)
>     at options.error (C:\Users\Sabbir\test\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:294:32)  @
> ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss  @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js
> ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from proper instalation.
You can install Bulma is few different ways.

If you're compiling assets with Laravel Mix try following

In terminal install Bulma using NPM `npm install -D bulma
In your app.scss file include it at the top.

```
// If you need to modify Bulma variables to so before importing it!

$link: $oc-blue-5;
@import './node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass';
```

more:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/bulmaio?page=1

Comment: Thanks... Problem solved . but I can't use Bootstrap and Bulma at the same time

Comment: Bootstrap and Bulma are two different frameworks. They can overwrite its commends. I guess the best way will be to add each on the top of html doc.

Comment: If i helped you please check answer as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
@import '~bulma/bulma.sass';
```